# Is it possible to set a Bitmap in a rounded rect in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-custom-view

Hello: Here is the question:

I've got a custom view. It's shape is an rounded rectangle. (as drawn in its onDraw Method). 
I've got a Bitmap that I want to set it as background. I can use the method:

```
void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)
```

To scale the image to rectangle smaller thant the shape of my view but I would like for it to occupy the whole view. Is there any way to crop the image corners so the match a rounded rectangle?

Comment: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

Comment: to close the question, the link again as an answer: have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

Comment: Strange, i can not post it as an answer, he always converts it to a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question, I am posting the comment with a bit more text.

The answer can be found in the following question:

[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)